# @font-face for the drop down is not working in ie8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, font-face

While using @font-face I am facing a problem that is when I am going to convert the font from hindi to english, this is working fine in each and every browser for each datacontrol. but for dropdownlist this is not good in IE8 but fine in other browsers.I am using it in the following way:

1) in app_theme folder

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "MyCustomFont";
    src: url('../font/MFDEV010.ttf') format('truetype')
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: "MyFont";
    src: url('../font/MFDEV010.eot?iefix') format('eot')

}

.HindiSkin
{
    font-family: "MyFont", "MyCustomFont";
    font-size:17px;

}
.EngSkin
{
    font-family: Arial Unicode MS ;
    font-size:15px;

}

.InputSelect
{
   /*border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;*/
   font-family: verdana;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #090908;
   font-weight: normal;
   width: 190px;
   padding:1px;
   height:25px;
}

.InputSelectHindi
{
   /*border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;*/
   font-family: "MyCustomFont","MyFont";
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #090908;
   font-weight: normal;
   width: 190px;
   padding:1px;
   height:30px;
}
```

2) in the skin file i have include:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" cssclass="InputSelect" />
<asp:DropDownList SkinID="Blue" runat="server" cssclass="InputSelectHindi" />
```

3) on the page

```
on the page i have add the reference of the theme here like this:
StylesheetTheme="EnglishFontSkin"
```

Note: this is working fine everywhere but not IE8, please give the solution for it. 
      thnx in advance

Comment: Did you read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ?

Comment: yes but cant get success for my problem, Here I am using the ttf and eot fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support TTF format in font-face (acording to [this page](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=@font-face_browser_support)). Maybe that's the reason?